# Retrieving google analytics data with Tibco BW

Tags: google-analytics, tibco

I would like to extract data with google analytics api to tibco Business works. But i am not sure what the best pratice would be. First i thought about using java code for requests and responses. I have been looking at this tutorial.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/articles/hello-analytics-api

But now i am not sure if that is the best idea. Would it be better or even possible  to do with Tibco:s http-palettes? Can i autenticate i user then? I would appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: can you please tell me what is your exact requirement?

Comment: I need to retrieve as much data as possible from the google analytics account in a business process. Data should firstly be stored in one system as xml and the later be sent to another system. Thats pretty much all information i have.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the [BW HTTP Activities](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/activematrix_businessworks/5.11.0-november-2012/doc/html/tib_bw_palette_reference/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm#context=tib_bw_palette_reference&file=palref.5.069.htm) to integrate with the [Google Analytics' RESTful API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference). However, to make things easier, you might want to consider using the [BW Plugin for REST and JSON](https://docs.tibco.com/products/tibco-activematrix-businessworks-plug-in-for-rest-and-json-1-1-0), which will take care of the JSON parsing and OAUTH implementation for you.

Otherwise, the easiest option is to just use the [Google's Java Client Library](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/) and [BW's Java Activities](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/activematrix_businessworks/5.11.0-november-2012/doc/html/tib_bw_palette_reference/palref.5.076.htm)

Comment: Thanks for your answear. I ended up using google´s Java Client Library and BW java activity. It works the only issue i can see is that it could be a bit hard to maintain with all the Java code.